# MacBook display stays on in clamshell mode

Tags: display, closed-clamshell

I'm running two external displays from a MacBook Pro 16 inch in closed clamshell mode.

I notice however that the internal display is still on as well: it is pictured as a third screen in System Preferences > Displays, and when I open the lid ever so slightly, I can see it.

When I use the laptop without external displays, the display turns off as it should when closing the lid.

I've tried to reset SMC and NVRAM but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a faulty angle sensor, which had to be replaced.